# Repeat Column Headers in BI Publisher Excel Templates in fusion

Tags: excel, oracle, business-intelligence, bi-publisher, excel-template

In fusion BIP report, when data in excel template exceeds 65536 rows it gets splitted into multiple sheets.
I have a requirement to repeat column headers in BI publisher excel templates when the data split into multiple sheets.
For every sheet column headers should be repeated. Currently it is showing column header in first sheet only.
Any help/ pointer is appreciated. Is it a limitation of the BI publisher excel templates.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing this Excel export with so many rows so you can do data manipulation in Excel. And in that case, formatting is not relevant.

Solve the root cause, not the headers. Instead of doing a BI Publisher Excel output, use a E-Text output and put it into CSV or similar form. You will notice it runs and saves faster too as there's no formatting markup in the Excel output to deal with.